# What to wear in Switzerland in July?

Tags: switzerland, clothing

I am aware that the weather changes often and that I should wear layers, but I also read that locals tend to dress quite modestly (dark, plain clothing). Is that so? I will note that I am going to a few metal concerts and festivals - should I still dress classy?

Comment: Depends on where in Switzerland. Big cities like Zurich or Basel are fairly cosmopolitan and with lots of culturally variety. As you go more rural and/or up into the mountains, things get more conservative and the higher you are, the colder it gets.

Comment: It depends on where you want to go. No, no need to wear classy, but it could rain, and if you are in some metal open airs in mountains (and valleys), bring also something warm (just in case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clothing locals wear will change with fashion, so what was noticed last year will likely not be the same this year and will be different again next year. And what you describe sounds like office workers on their way to work.

You will be a foreign visitor and as such you will stand out whatever you do, it is almost impossible to blend in and it is useless as it will not help you with anything.

If you go as a tourist, I would dress in the style you would when going to a different part of your own country, when going into town you would wear a milder version of your style than you would when going to a concert. That will do for Switzerland as well.

Being dressed in 'metal' styles will likely help you get in with people who also like that music, while when being dressed as an office worker will not get you anything.

On the other hand, if you plan to combine business with metal concerts in one trip, you best bring business style clothing. You do not need to adjust to what you assume is Swiss style, what you would wear at home going to work or business casual if your contacts allow it.

Comment: Being dressed in a suit or in business casual will make it easier to meet fellow office workers or businessmen :)

Comment: @JonathanReez, I included an option of business meetings.

Comment: @JonathanReez But does wearing loafers make it easier to meet bakers?

Comment: Yes, and if they're penny loafers, you can meet bankers too.